# Mocking injected class

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a class which has a dependency injected into it's base class.

```
class Parent{
   protected PersistentCache dataCache;
}


<bean id="parent" class="xxxx.parent" abstract="true" init-method="init"
        p:dataCache-ref="persistentCache"
        ......"/>
```

The method under test in the child uses this cache:

```
class Child extends Parent{
  public prepareData(){
      ......
      Data data = dataCache.get(...);
      ........
  }
}
```

How do I mock the get method in dataCache to return a 'dummy' while writing the unit test for prepareData?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter, that it is in super class, you can mock it as regular method.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class Testing {

  @Mock
  PersistentCache dataCache;

  @InjectMocks
  Child child;

  @Before
  public void abc() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }
  @Test
  public void test() {

   doReturn(dummyData).when(dataCache).get();
   child.PrepareData();
  }
}
```

Comment: I assume by child.xyz() you mean child.prepareData(). Why spy and not @Mock? Also initMocks shouldn't be needed when using the mockitoJunitRUnner

Comment: It is okay. just copy pasted some code. Mock is also good. ya by xyz I mean any method